# Wrong grub after installing Kali over Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, system-installation, grub2

I had Ubuntu 16.04.
I created a Kali USB live.

I boot on this USB and install Kali on an encrypted LVM.
At the end of the install guide, I don't get the option to install Grub (as it is probably detecting the Grub from Ubuntu)

Install goes ok but when I reboot I get the Grub command prompt. 
On top is written `GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11`

I try commands like "`find`" or "`load kernel`" but none are recognised.
I can't find the configfile to modify it.

When I `ls` volumes I find in hd0,gpt2 the efi folder qnd the system, config, initrd and vmlinuz of kali. But when I try to `set root=(hd0,gpt2)` I get q unknown filesystem error.

How could I install a fresh Grub version ?

Comment: `hd0,gpt2` might not be a kali-linux filesystem. It might be `hd0,gpt3` or `hd0,gpt 4`. Try them all.

Comment: Good thing you keep full hard drive image backups.  Time to do a restore and have another go at it.